# Simple Flask app and Bad HTTP/0.9 request type over time

Tags: python, flask

I wrote simple flask application like here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/ It's really minimalistic, has only three pages and login form. And I run this application on my own computer. Sometimes over the day i get this:

```
178.93.*.* - - [27/Jun/2013 07:28:45] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\x99L\xe6\x1f\x9a\xbb\x8d\xea\x1d\xfa\x96_\x8e\x88\xc1\xfc_q\x8d:h\x88\x12\xda\xcb\x1a4X\xa7\xe3;\x1e\x1a\xd1w')
178.93.*.* - - [27/Jun/2013 07:28:45] "�L�������_��_q�:h���4X��;�w ���|G�(+��g��(RhԱ����" 400 -
```

My index function is here:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if database.get_user(request.form['login']):
            session['username'] = request.form['login']
            return redirect(url_for('list_site'))

        elif request.form['login'] == app.config['USERNAME']:
            if request.form['password'] == app.config['PASSWORD']:
                session['logged_in_admin'] = True
                return redirect(url_for('admin_site'))

    return render_template('index.html')
```

Sometimes server is not responding and I must restart app. Can someone help me?

Comment: Turn off all your browser extensions, and try again.

Comment: @falsetru it's not my ip, when I am going to site everything is ok. Sometimes some ip's is generating this bad request.

Comment: @user84471 ,How did u resolve this issue ?

Comment: @uttam it was because I had https not http requests.